# html5 swipe events

Tags: html, touch, swipe

I am pretty new to HTML5. Coming from Flash background, I can call the swipe events easily from Actionscript API. But for HTML5, I believe I have to code this myself by listening to touchstart, touchmove, and touchend. Is there a simpler way to do this? And also I am looking for a website that contains complete HTML5 references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet for handling touch events is to look at some JavaScript libraries that can handle them:  [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) and [jQT](http://jqtjs.com/) (formerly jQTouch) are the big ones.

If you're not already using [JQuery](http://jquery.com), I would **highly** recommend it.

As far as HTML references, the (highly verbose and technical) [specification document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/) might be too much, so I would suggest starting with [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp).  (A tip: Keep in mind that HTML5 is still a work in progress and browser/client support varies.)

If you need help figuring out how to manipulate the DOM (i.e. how to use JavaScript to make things happen), the JQuery documentation is also be a good reference point.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have been using JQuery for awhile. So I have the basic of DOM  manipulation. Just need to get myself up to date with all the HTML5 tags.